# SQL "an error occurred during local report processing"

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Apologies first of all if there is an answer to this elsewhere on the site. I've checked some of the proposed solutions and can't find anything appropriate.

So I've got this SSRS report that works fine when deployed but won't run locally during testing. The main query itself works when run in the query editor, as do all the sub queries that provide data for parameter drop lists but when I try to preview it, I get the error.

Bear in mind it used to work, up until the end of last year, which was when it was last updated.

I've tried removing all the tables and matrices on a copy (replacing with one very simple table), the parameters went too and I still get the error.  I've also downloaded the server version, renamed it and redeployed it, works online, but not locally.  As the error message is brutally vague, I've run out of ideas of things to try.  Apart from switching over to PowerBI, can anyone think of anything else I could do to understand where the error is from?

Possibly relevant - the main query has some recursion in a subquery, but only a couple of levels.  Could this be related?  As I've said before, it used to work...

PS I'm using VS 16.7.2 from server V13.0.4466.4
PPS I also added the query to a brand new report and it errored so I think it must be something related to the SQL itself?

Comment: _related to the SQL itself_, well show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: is it possibly that the local account does not have access to the data source, but on the server a different account is used to run the report? That would explain why it works on the server and not locally!

Comment: Try putting your SQL query in a stored procedure in the database for better performance and execution. Then reference this stored procedure in your report. Easier to isolate the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really show any sample data due to data security issues.  I did consider the local account permissions, but the report did work when I posted it originally, and I've made no changes to any of the accounts.  I am going to try creating an SP though as it's probably a good idea whether the query is working locally or not.